# How to not overlap the text on buttons in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

[image]

So, in my password field, I tried adding these icons as buttons. Now issue that I am facing is text is getting overlapped on that button. What actually I wanted is buttons stays inside the edittext but text doesnt overlap on it, but still you should be able to write the more content, it will be just scrollable.

for this I have used a constraint layout with editText and 2 buttons.
Below is the code for that, for reference

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     android:id="@+id/customEditTextLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                        style="@style/editTextInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:letterSpacing="@dimen/letterSpace0_1"

                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                     />

                    <Button
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:id="@+id/eyeIcon"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp30"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/show_eye_black_24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextPassword"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/fingerprintIcon"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_5"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dp10"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"/>

                    <Button
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:id="@+id/fingerprintIcon"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp30"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_black_24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_5"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp10"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp_5"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/dp10"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the text from overlapping the `Button`s, you can set a padding to the end of the `EditText`:

```
android:paddingEnd="90dp"
```

This way, the `EditText` underline will still be showing beneath the two `Button`s.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a quick handy solution on that. It works on all screen sizes too like tablet, mobile phones

Answer (score 0):

All your views have `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` which means they are all centered vertically hence why they overlap. Now do you want them on the same line horizontally or on the same row vertically?

**Edit:**
Being at work, I could not display the picture. You can achieve this with [Barriers](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html). Now you should read and understand the provided link which explains it in details with visual animations. It might seem hard at the beginning, but it is worth understanding, you will not be able to live without it. It will allow your to tell the `EditText` to never overlap.

Comment: Hi the layout is fine enough, my issue is when you write text in password field, it overlaps those buttons and goes ahead

Comment: Your password's view has width as `match_parent` and at the same time `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` . Is that normal? It is the same thing horizontally wise. Now you could use the constraintLayout's [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline) and event [Barriers](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) start and end to make sure it doesn't overlap.

Comment: okay I got what you are trying to say, and i changed my editText constraints a bit from that, maybe idk if that looks good or not. You can suggest me something on that        `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/eyeIcon"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use two linear layouts main layout with vertical orientation and a linear layout for the edit text and buttons with horizontal orientation ? not sure if this is what you want tho...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5px">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_show_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="icon"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_fingerprint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="icon"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```